# Duplicate (copy) a project from INET and paste it in omnet

Tags: omnet++, inet

**Hi everyone,
I want to edit one of the Inet project based on my need. But I do not want to change the original project in Inet. However, when I copied and pasted under samples folder in omnet, it did not work. Is anyone know how can I do this?
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new project and also keep the INET project open in the workspace. Then open your project's Property menu (right click / Properties) and set INET as a referenced project. That way all NED types defined in INET will be available also in your separate project.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rudi.